# Copy text file content to another text file

Tags: visual-c++

How to copy from one text file to another text file?
Here my current progress.. it just copy the last line of the source file :(

```
        ifstream stream1("c:\\source.txt");

        char a[512];


        while(!stream1.eof())

        {
          stream1 >> a;
        }


   ofstream myfile;
   myfile.open ("c:\\destination.txt");
   myfile << a;
   myfile.close();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple solution:

```
ifstream stream1("C:/source.txt");
ofstream stream2("C:/target.txt");
stream2 << stream1.rdbuf();
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind this is `a` being a char array, not a stream. So every loop you're writing to the same position in memory (and don't append instead).

You could just create the `ofstream` object on the beginning and write from stream to stream:

```
#include <fstream>

void main()
{
    std::ifstream stream1("C:\\source.txt");
    std::ofstream stream2("C:\\target.txt");

    while(!stream1.eof())
        stream2 << stream1;

    stream1.close();
    stream2.close();
}
```

Comment: the error msg is :  Error 1 error C2679: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::ofstream' (or there is no acceptable conversion) c:\test.cpp

Comment: Just <fstream> - although the streams have to be swapped inside the while loop. Updating the answer ... If you encounter an error like that, just try swapping the direction.